# I am trying to complete the first game project in python crash course book

Tags: python

It appears that my while loop is not having any effect when I run the code. I am not able to change the color of the screen or add my image. I suspect I am making some type of simple formatting error as I am very new to Python. Thanks!

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship


def run_game():
    # Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')

    # Make a ship
    ship = Ship(screen)

    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:

        # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        ship.blitme()

        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()


run_game()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually render the game and flip it onto the display. So your code would look like this`

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship


def run_game():
    # Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')
    ship = Ship(screen)

    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:

    # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

    # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        ship.blitme()
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()  
run_game()
```

`